# How to 'batch copy and paste' VSE strips in Blender?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, workflow

I am using Blender as a video editor. I have a video I am working on, an interview that fades in and out from footage to title card, in and out. I am adding the effects: color, gamma cross, etc. There are a lot of title cards. I was hoping that fade process could be automated or at the very least, group select the effects I made, and then copy and paste. I know there is duplicate, but I want to do several at a time, not just one strip. Ideally, I can copy and paste the fade in out sequence where only the title card is different. Therefore, I do not have to go through the color/gamma cross in and out many times. Is there no way to speed up my work flow? Keep in mind, this is being on done on computer, so repetitive tasks are what machines do best. Surely I do not have to keep doing repetitive tasks when I ought to be able to drag and drop an effect?